# Pagebreak to contain read more link

Tags: html, css, page-break

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a page break set of html convert into a read more link.

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
<span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I've seen something similar in WordPress that makes the content past the line break not appear on the page. Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: Unless there is more to it, this really has nothing to do with CF. (Removed unrelated CF references).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a WYSIWYG editor such as tinyMCE, you can use the horizontal line as a separator for example.

Then, using php, you do an explode using the html code of your separator and you display only the first value of your array as an introduction text.

That's how i do it, there might be better ways.